# Error while executing an if statement in R

Tags: r, text-processing

I have this small function to obtain an Assonance Score for text

```
getAssonanceScore <- function(book, count) {
  #for each sentence

  for (i in length(book[[1]])){
    words <- strsplit(book[i], "\\ ")

      for (j in length(words[[1]])){
         if (substr(words[[1]][j],1,1) == substr(words[[1]][j+1],1,1) ) {
          count <- count + 1 
         }

      }

  }

  count <- count / length(book)

  return (count)
}
```

What it does is that it gets a list with one line of text in its 1st position and a second line of text on its second position and so on. After getting this line it splits the sentence, and puts it into a list containing all the constituent words. What I do with that is that I compare the first letter of the first word to the first letter of the second word, and the first letter of the second word with the first letter of the 3rd to obtain a total assonance score. This is then divided by the length of the book. When I try to test this function with a small input list 'word' of the form:

```
> words
[1] "babbling brook by blue grass"
```

it gives me this error:

```
> Error in if (substr(words[[1]][j], 1, 1) == substr(words[[1]][j + 1], 
> :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am working in RStudio, and very much a beginner to R, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: It should be getAlliterationScore instead of getAssonanceScore :D

Comment: Your if statement is somehow returning a NA (hence missing value where true/false error). Are you sure neither of substr(words[[1]][j],1,1) and substr(words[[1]][j+1],1,1) are null?

Comment: `j+1` gets bigger than `length(words[[1]])` in the only iteration your loop does.

Comment: Note that when you divide by `length(book)`, you are dividing by the number of lines in the book, not the number of words (so in your example case it would divide by 1, not by 5). Did you mean to use number of words? Also note that you will never compare from one line to the next with this approach- do you want to do so?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks very much for pointing that out! I think I mean to divide it by the number of words, just changed to include this line : 
 **totalWords <- totalWords + length(words[[1]])** just after **words <- strsplit(book[i], "\\ ")**
and then dividing by totalWords at the end and it works!

Comment: @QPTR Do you want to compare the last word of one line to the first word of the next line? If so, an easier thing to do would be `all_words <- unlist(strsplit(book, " "))` to get a vector of all words- then you don't need the outer for loop at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for j in length(words[[1]])` doesn't do what you expect it to; `j` is only ever equal to the full length of the list. This also means that `j + 1` runs off the end of the list (so that `words[[1]][j + 1]` returns `NA`).

Change your `for` loop line to

```
        for (j in seq_len(length(words[[1]]) - 1)) {
```

Now

```
getAssonanceScore("babbling brook by blue grass", 0)
```

returns 3.

As noted in the comments, a better, computationally more efficient, and more concise approach would be

```
all_words <- unlist(strsplit(book, " "))
count <- sum(substr(head(all_words, -1), 1, 1) ==
             substr(tail(all_words, -1), 1, 1))
```

Comment: And using `seq_len` would be even better.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thank you very much, that works! is -1 to prevent j+1 from exceeding the length of the list? Also, I think I am making the same mistake in the outer loop, would changing it to 'for (i in 1:length(book[[1]]))' would be better or using seq_len?

Comment: @QPTR That's right about the `-1`. And you probably meant for the outer loop to go up to `length(book)`, not `length(book[[1]])`. You could replace that with `for (i in seq_along(book)) {`

Comment: @DavidRobinson Actually I want to iterate along all the sentences in the book, at the moment it is just a single sentence, so wouldn't that be book[[1]] if suppose there were two lines stored?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I think I got your point, I do mean book and not book[[1]] because even though its a list of character vectors outside the function, I am passing only one character vector into the function.

Comment: @QPTR You're passing only one character vector into the function, but is it always a character vector of length 1? (And if so, why have that `for (i in length(book[[1]])){` loop at all?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Nope, its a character vector of differing sizes, each vector containing all the lines of the entire book, and one position of the vector containing one line.

Comment: @QPTR In that case, you do need the loop to be `for (i in seq_along(book)) ` (or `1:length(book)`, but definitely not `length(book[[1]])` anywhere). Your loop otherwise only examines the first line in the character vector passed to the function.

Comment: Aha, got it! Thanks . Basically my code in the main part looks something like this: 

`input.dir <- "C:/mallet/my-data"
filenames.v <- dir(path=input.dir, pattern=".*txt")
file.path(input.dir, filenames.v)
books <- list()

for (i in 1:length(filenames.v))
{
  filepath <- file.path(input.dir, filenames.v[i])
  novel.v <- scan(filepath, what = "character", sep ="\n")
  #write code for remove quotes and extra spaces
  score <- getAssonanceScore(novel.v, 0, 0)
  books[[filenames.v[i]]] <- novel.v
}` I am sorry, the formatting is going a bit topsy-turvy.

Comment: @QPTR I understand. Finally- as I note in the comments above you are never comparing the last word of one line to the first word of the next line. Do you want to do so? If so, you should do `all_words <- unlist(strsplit(book, " "))` at the start of your function, then iterate over `all_words` instead of words. This removes the need for a loop over the lines in a book.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thats a very awesome idea! And I just tried doing it with this code: `all_words <- unlist(strsplit(book, " "))
  for (i in seq_along(all_words)) {
    
    if (substr(all_words[i],1,1) == substr(all_words[i+1],1,1) ) {
      count <- count + 1 
    }
    
  }` and its giving me 'the missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' even though it seem to work when I try to work it out in the console.

Comment: @QPTR Change `for (i in seq_along(all_words))` to `for (i in seq_len(length(all_words) - 1))`

Comment: @QPTR Also, please note that an easier, and computationally faster, way to do that would be `count <- sum(substr(head(all_words, -1), 1, 1) == substr(tail(all_words, -1), 1, 1))`, which avoids the need for a for loop at all.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Wow. Could you please explain what the -1 does? On reading head and tail functions it seem the return the first or last rows according to the number specified so what would a negative argument return?

Comment: @QPTR `head(x, -1)` returns all except the last value in a vector. `tail(x, -1)` returns all except the first value in a vector. We've therefore created two vectors, one missing the first and one missing the last, which means if we compare the two everything is lined up next to its adjacent element

Comment: @DavidRobinson Very, very cool, thank you very much, you have given me a lot to learn! And it works perfectly !